# Java JodaTime split timeRange

Tags: java, jodatime

In my application I have an object which looks like this:

```
MyObject interval1 = new MyObject()
interval1.start = new DateTime(...) // e.g. 2016-03-30 09:00
interval1.end= new DateTime(...)    // e.g. 2016-03-30 16:30
```

and a second one

```
MyObject interval2 = new MyObject()
interval2.start = new DateTime(...) // e.g. 2016-03-30 08:00
interval2.end= new DateTime(...)    // e.g. 2016-03-30 11:00
```

Interval2 can be one of in the picture at bottom.

My question now would be if someone knows a simple possibility with JodaTime to split interval1 by interva2:

e.g in the example above I should get an object which looks like this (this is case 1 in the picture):

```
newInteval3.start = new DateTime(); // 2016-03-30 11:00
newInteval3.end= new DateTime(); // 2016-03-30 16:30
```

I have tried it with ifs (start.isEqual(..), start.isAfter(..), start.isBefore()) but this is horrible.

[image: Interval]

Comment: would a combination of contains and periodBeforeEnd and periodAfterStart help? These are all methods available in the Joda Interval class.

Comment: Can you please describe your term "split"? Is it meant as a kind of minus-operation `interval1 - interval2` containing all time points in `interval1` which are not in `interval2`? Your example for case 1 seems to indicate that. But what about your expectation for the result in other cases? Shall case 4, 7, 8 produce an empty interval? And case 3 two smaller intervals?